# Ubuntu 14.04 wireless network not working

Tags: wireless

I'm writing this post via LAN, I want to wake up my wireless network.

I saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/835286), so wireless information is like below. How can I fix it

> #### wireless info START
>
> Report from: 30 May 2018 00:55 KST +0900
>
> Booted last: 30 May 2018 00:45 KST +0900
>
> Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000
>
> release
>
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Release: 14.04
>   Codename: trusty
>
> kernel
>
> Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC
>   2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
>
> desktop
>
> Ubuntu
>
> lspci
>
> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042]
>   (rev 31)  Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:4133]
>     Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
>
> 04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168]
>   (rev 15)  Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c790]
>     Kernel driver in use: r8169
>
> lsusb
>
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 001
>   Device 005: ID 2232:1080 Silicon Motion  Bus 001 Device 004: ID
>   0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc.  Bus 001 Device 003: ID
>   0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 040b:2013 Weltrend Semiconductor  Bus 001
>   Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> PCMCIA card info
>   
>   rfkill
>
> 0: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN     Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 1:
>   samsung-bluetooth: Bluetooth  Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 2:
>   hci0: Bluetooth   Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no
>
> lsmod
>
> ath10k_pci             40960  0  ath10k_core           311296  1
>   ath10k_pci ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core mac80211
>   733184  1 ath10k_core mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau cfg80211
>   557056  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core wmi                    20480  2
>   mxm_wmi,nouveau
>
> interfaces
>
> [/etc/network/interfaces] auto lo iface lo inet loopback
>
> ifconfig
>
> docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
>             inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
>             inet addr:203.252.106.81  Bcast:203.252.106.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
>             inet6 addr: fe80::/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:93735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:50050 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:134826832 (134.8 MB)  TX bytes:4156592 (4.1 MB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:1158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:1158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
>             RX bytes:222117 (222.1 KB)  TX bytes:222117 (222.1 KB)
>
> iwconfig
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> docker0   no wireless extensions.
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> route
>
> Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask
>   Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>   0.0.0.0         203.252.106.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
>   172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
>   203.252.106.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     1      0        0 eth0
>
> resolv.conf
>
> nameserver 127.0.1.1
>
> network managers
>
> Installed:
>
> NetworkManager
>
> Running:
>
> root       727     1  0 00:45 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager
>
> NetworkManager info
>
> NetworkManager Tool
>
> State: connected (global)
>
> - Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------   Type:              Wired   Driver:            r8169   State:             connected   Default:
>     yes   HW Address:
>
>   Capabilities:
>     Carrier Detect:  yes
>     Speed:           1000 Mb/s
>
>   Wired Properties
>     Carrier:         on
>
>   IPv4 Settings:
>     Address:         203.252.106.81
>     Prefix:          25 (255.255.255.128)
>     Gateway:         203.252.106.1
>
>   DNS:             203.252.96.77
>
> NetworkManager.state
>
> [main] NetworkingEnabled=true WirelessEnabled=true WWANEnabled=true
>   WimaxEnabled=true
>
> NetworkManager.conf
>
> [main] plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono dns=dnsmasq
>
> [ifupdown] managed=false
>
> NetworkManager profiles
>   
>   Netplan config
>   
>   iw reg get
>
> Region: Asia/Seoul (based on set time zone)
>
> country 00:   (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)     (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20),
>   PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS     (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM,
>   PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS     (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN,
>   NO-IBSS   (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
>
> iwlist channels
>
> lo        no frequency information.
>
> docker0   no frequency information.
>
> eth0      no frequency information.
>
> iwlist scan
>
> lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
>
> docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.
>
> eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
>
> module infos
>
> [ath10k_pci] filename:
>   /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
>   firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin firmware:
>   ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware.bin license:        Dual BSD/GPL
>   description:    Driver support for Atheros QCA988X PCIe devices
>   author:         Qualcomm Atheros srcversion:
>   8CBDAC7980FC042032AE6A6 depends:        ath10k_core intree:         Y
>   vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  parm:
>   irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint) parm:
>   reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)
>
> [ath10k_core] filename:
>   /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko license:        Dual BSD/GPL description:    Core module for QCA988X
>   PCIe devices. author:         Qualcomm Atheros srcversion:
>   F5C0E3964FCD86D0F5FE986 depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath intree: 
>   Y vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  parm:
>   debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint) parm:           uart_print:Uart
>   target debugging (bool) parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for
>   calibration in testmode (bool) parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode:
>   0-hardware, 1-software (uint) parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11
>   frame datapath (bool)
>
> [ath] filename:
>   /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
>   license:        Dual BSD/GPL description:    Shared library for
>   Atheros wireless LAN cards. author:         Atheros Communications
>   srcversion:     3FCDBF7CE71CB8FB980D59D depends:        cfg80211
>   intree:         Y vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload
>   modversions
>
> [mac80211] filename:
>   /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko license:
>   GPL description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem srcversion:
>   2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44 depends:        cfg80211 intree:         Y
>   vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  parm:
>   minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta.
>   (bool) parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries
>   before disconnecting (reason 4). (int) parm:
>   max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4).
>   (int) parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals
>   before we decide beacon was lost. (int) parm:
>   probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before
>   disconnecting (reason 4). (int) parm:
>   ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211
>   to use (charp)
>
> [cfg80211] filename:
>   /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
>   description:    wireless configuration support license:        GPL
>   author:         Johannes Berg srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
>   depends:         intree:         Y vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic
>   SMP mod_unload modversions  parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE
>   802.11 regulatory domain code (charp) parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band
>   (bool)
>
> module parameters
>
> [ath10k_pci] irq_mode: 0 reset_mode: 0
>
> [ath10k_core] cryptmode: 0 debug_mask: 0 rawmode: N skip_otp: N
>   uart_print: N
>
> [mac80211] beacon_loss_count: 7 ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
>   max_nullfunc_tries: 2 max_probe_tries: 5 minstrel_vht_only: Y
>   probe_wait_ms: 500
>
> [cfg80211] cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N ieee80211_regdom: 00
>
> /etc/modules
>
> lp rtc
>
> modprobe options
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf] blacklist ath_pci
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf] blacklist evbug blacklist usbmouse
>   blacklist usbkbd blacklist eepro100 blacklist de4x5 blacklist eth1394
>   blacklist snd_intel8x0m blacklist snd_aw2 blacklist i2c_i801 blacklist
>   prism54 blacklist bcm43xx blacklist garmin_gps blacklist asus_acpi
>   blacklist snd_pcsp blacklist pcspkr blacklist amd76x_edac
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf] alias net-pf-3 off alias
>   net-pf-6 off alias net-pf-9 off alias net-pf-11 off alias net-pf-12
>   off alias net-pf-19 off alias net-pf-21 off alias net-pf-36 off
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf] remove iwlwifi \ (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o
>   -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \ && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
>
> [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf] softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
>
> rc.local
>
> exit 0
>
> pm-utils
>   
>   udev rules
>
> [/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
>
> ## PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169) SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="",
>
> ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
>
> dmesg
>
> [    2.071260] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2 [    2.071280]
>   ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2 [
>   2.071289] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2 [    2.071304] ath10k_pci
>   0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2 [
>   2.071306] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2 [    2.071318] ath10k_pci
>   0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2 [
>   2.071319] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2 [    2.071458] ath10k_pci
>   0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2 [
>   2.071460] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2 [    2.071466] ath10k_pci
>   0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2 [    2.071471]
>   ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2) [    2.071473]
>   ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2) [
>   2.071474] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2) [    2.226364] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times) [    2.226462] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready [    6.088919] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link up [    6.088939] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready [  577.051058] IPv6:
>   ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
>
> #### wireless info END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see this in your log:

```
 [ 2.071473] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
 [ 2.071474] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

Let's install the firmware. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot.

Comment: After two commands which you offered, other error is occurred `dpkg-deb: error: archive 'linux-firmware_1.173_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive linux-firmware_1.173_all.deb (--install):`

Comment: I closed terminal and reopened, `sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb` error is occurred.

Comment: It the result improved with this package? http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.3_all.deb

Comment: After download that package, just type command what you said above?

Comment: WOW, it is solved THANK YOU!!! SORRY FOR MY LOW LEVEL TO GIVE YOU UP BUTTON.